# Command to reindex all mongodb collections

Tags: mongodb, indexing

References to reindexing MongoDB collections are usually per collection:

```
db.mycollection.reIndex();
```

I'd like to reindex a number of collections all at once. One-by-one can get a bit tiring.

What's the appropriate command to issue `reIndex();` across all collections?

Comment: I'm curious, what's your use case where you need to re-index your collections?

Comment: Maybe he's migrating to new index format (it was changed quite a some time ago).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about this? It's still one-by-one for the database, but just one command for you.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(coll_name) {
  var coll = db.getCollection(coll_name);
  coll.reIndex();
});
```

Answer (score 22):

Slightly smaller version of Sergio's answer:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection){db[collection].reIndex()});
```

There is no need to get a reference to the collection first.