# Do I need to reindex MongoDB Collection after some period of time like RDBMS

Tags: mongodb

I like to get some knowledge on reindexing the MongoDB. Please forgive me as I am asking some subjective questions.

The questinon is : Do MongoDB needs to do reindexing periodically like we do for RDBMS or Mongo automatically manages it.

Thanks for your fedback

Answer (score 7):

That's a good question, because [nowhere in the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/) does it mention explicitly that indexes are automatically maintained*. But, they are. You [rarely need to reindex manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187225/command-to-reindex-all-mongodb-collections#comment16317856_12187225).

---

<sup>*I [filed a bug for that](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-2810), go vote for it :)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also checked the docs and not find one constructive answer for this question.

Comment: need to file another ticket? https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-2810

Answer (score 7):

> Mongodb takes care of indexes during routine updates. This operation
>   may be expensive for collections that have a large amount of data
>   and/or a large number of indexes.For most users, the reIndex command
>   is unnecessary. However, it may be **worth running if the collection
>   size has changed significantly or if the indexes are consuming a
>   disproportionate amount of disk space**.
>
> ```
> Call reIndex using the following form:
> ```
>
> db.collection.reIndex();

Reference : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.reIndex/